# How do i separate each HTML Canvas Path/Shape to be filled individually?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have been practicing using Javascript and Canvas and i have come to the issue where i am rendering a shape or two and a few lines to create a custom shape. Now i need to be able to color each one individually however when i use new Image(); on which is meant to the the first shape, the texture is rendered on the last ctx shape drawn.

here is my code:

> https://jsfiddle.net/3dk4447k/2/

```
renderCanvas: function(topLength, heightLength, slant) {
var canvases = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("DesignerCanvas"));

for (var canvas of canvases) {

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;

  // String for Hanging
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(150, 0, 3, 75);
    ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Top Trimming
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( ( 150 - ( topLength / 2 ) ) , 80 );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , 70, 150 + ( topLength / 2 ), 80);
    ctx.lineTo( 150 + ( topLength / 2 ), 83 );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , 73, 150 - ( topLength / 2 ), 83);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();

  // Shade Outter Body
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( 150 + ( topLength / 2 ), 83 );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , 73, 150 - (topLength / 2), 83);
    ctx.lineTo( 150 - (( topLength / 2 ) + slant), heightLength );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , ( heightLength - 10 ), 150 + ( (topLength / 2 ) + slant ), heightLength);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();

  // Shade Inner Body
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( 150 + ( (topLength / 2) + slant ), heightLength );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , (heightLength - 10), 150 - ((topLength / 2) + slant ), heightLength);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , (heightLength + 5), 150 + ((topLength / 2) + slant ), heightLength);
    ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  // Bottom Trimming
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( 150 + ((topLength / 2) + slant ), (heightLength - 3) );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , (heightLength - 15), 150 - ((topLength / 2) + slant ), (heightLength - 3));
    ctx.lineTo( 150 - ((topLength / 2) + slant ), heightLength );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , (heightLength + 5), 150 + ((topLength / 2) + slant ), heightLength);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();

}
},

init: function () {
console.log("Product Designer: Initialized.");
this.bindActions();
this.renderPage("DesignerTab1", "DesignerPanel1");
}

}
```

Okay to clarify, my end result should basically the same as how it is now but with the ability to change the texture background of all Paths that i have made. eg First Path String should be able to fill with a image, the next Path Top Trimming should be able to fill with a image etc..

The Problem in my code is that when you place an image to the new Image() then the texture is rendering on the bottom of the entire shape, which is not what i want it should fill the top of the shape only.

Comment: Sorry not sure how to link my jsfiddle here

Comment: A link works just fine.

Comment: Can you try to explain a bit more clearly what you're trying to accomplish? What should the end result be? Three separate images or just three differently colored shapes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is loaded asynchronously. The image's onload function is started after the renderCanvas function is completed. When the onload function is executed, the current path will be the last path defined in the renderCanvas function. To draw the image inside the desired path, you need to move the code defining the desired path inside the onload function. For example, change...

```
// String for Hanging
ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(150, 0, 3, 75);
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'image here';
  img.onload = function() {
      var pattern = ctx.createPattern(this,"repeat");
      ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
      ctx.fill();
  };
ctx.closePath();
```

to...

```
// String for Hanging
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'image here';
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(150, 0, 3, 75);
      var pattern = ctx.createPattern(this,"repeat");
      ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
      ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
};
```

Comment: Now this works to a degree thankyou, what happends tho if you have multiple canvases? i have the code inside a loop however the result is only displayed on the last canvas element out of 3? the other canvases dont get any render